# Camel unmarshaller supporting multiple dataformats

Tags: apache-camel, dataformat

Is there a Camel unmarshaler that I could use to unmarshal from **multiple** data formats (JSON, XML, etc) to, say XML?

This "universal" unmarshaller would then be used as, for example:

```
<route id="myRoute">
  <from uri="file:test/input"/>
  <!-- The input can be in JSON or in XML -->
  <unmarshal ref="universalUnmarshallerToXML"/>
  <!-- The input payload is always in XML -->
    <choice >
      <when>
          <xpath>/order/customer/country = 'US'</xpath>
          <to uri="file:test/output/us"/>
      </when>
      <when>
          <xpath>/order/customer/country = 'UK'</xpath>
          <to uri="file:test/output/uk"/>
      </when>
      <otherwise>
          <to uri="file:test/output/others"/>
      </otherwise>
  </choice>
</route>
```

Does this universal unmarshaller exist (hopefully it does), or should I implement my own?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's not exactly a *universal unmarshaller*, but similar to what you are asking for:

When you create a REST service, you can set a `BindingMode` so that Camel will unmarshal from JSON or XML automatically, depending on the incoming Content-Type:

```java
restConfiguration()
    .bindingMode(RestBindingMode.auto) // can also be .xml, .json,....
    .component("servlet");
```

But, I haven't seen this being feature used or exposed outside of REST services, yet.

Implementation is in [RestBindingAdvice](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/camel-3.2.0/core/camel-base/src/main/java/org/apache/camel/processor/RestBindingAdvice.java) if you're interested.

Comment: What if your incoming data was coming via File and not REST?